# Automatically clear a cell once a dropdown menu is cleared + fix local time

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am creating a shared agenda with different sheets (one per week) that has to be filled by different people. Every time they modify a certain cell (a drop-down menu), the date of change is reported in another cell on the same row.

I have currently two problems with my code:

1) I would like the date to be displayed as `dd/mm/yy`
2) If the modified cell is cleared (like if the text is deleted) or `-` (or `--` or `---`) is selected from the dropdown menu, also the date of change should disappear.

I find this type of code difficult to debug.

Here's the [Google Sheets file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZmmqPgH2lNC_eYivkYcKQrNH8BdM-g3z-ZVK5ePgxnM/edit?usp=sharing).

Comment: Can you post your code?... [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works for me this way:

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss=e.source;
  var rg=e.range;   
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(rg.columnStart!=2 && rg.columnStart!=10 && rg.columnStart!=18 && rg.columnStart!=26 && rg.columnStart!=34){return;}
  setClearOnNoValue(e);
}

function setClearOnNoValue(e) {
  var rg=e.range;
  var sh=rg.getSheet();
  if(e.value && e.value.length>0) {//added e.value.length>0
    sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, rg.columnStart + 3).setValue(Utilities.formatDate(new Date(new Date().getFullYear(),new Date().getMonth()+1,new Date().getDate(),new Date().getHours(),new Date().getMinutes()),Session.getScriptTimeZone(),"d/MMM/yyyy HH:mm"));
  }else{
    sh.getRange(rg.rowStart, rg.columnStart + 3).setValue('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your support! It works perfectly now.
Any idea about deleting the date of insertion if "-" or "--" or "---" is selected from the dropdown menu?

Comment: One question at a time.